# Turn navbar into full width searchbar via CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found this pretty neat [theme](http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-frostwave/) where the navbar turns into a full-width searchbar when clicking the magnifier icon. I was wondering how I could realise this. My attempt was to create an overlay input field and style it. But I assume there is something like a plugin or tutorial for it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do yourself without the need of a plugin.

I assume you are quite comfortable with HTML and CSS so I will summarise, but firstly I would create a DIV that is the same height as your header section, and CSS position it above the header.

Of course, inside this DIV you would put the search form.

Give the div 0 opacity and add CSS transitions:

```
div.search {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

When the page loads, the search bar will not be visible because we have set `opacity: 0;` However, using Javascript, we can add a `show` class to the search bar which will fade it in, and we can trigger this when a user clicks on something:

```
$('.search-trigger').click(function() {
    $('div.search').addClass('show');    
});
```

We would style the `show` class like this:

```
div.search.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: alright very clear so far, the bigger problem is, how I get the caret that big?

Comment: Excellent, what exactly do you mean by the caret?

Comment: You can't change the caret because it is part of your operating system. You can use a combination of CSS font-size and line-height to achieve the same effect they have on the site, but that's as much as you can do.